Search results are incomplete
E.g., https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Discord+gradio returns no results. Yet, a post contains both "Discord" and "gradio".

Not saying this isn't a bug, just offering some advice: When you're searching for something you know is in a post, you can wrap the terms in quotes (e.g. "Discord") and search that way. This works for sentence fragments, such as "yuvi posted this".
In this specific case, the term "Gradio" is only present in that post in a code block, which doesn't help Stack Overflow's already... Not-so-great search engine, and wouldn't turn up in a search for "Discord" "Gradio". So, in this case, if I perform a search for "Discord" code:"Gradio" it properly returns the post you reference.
Moral of the story is... Using quotes to perform an "exact-match" search really helps when you know a given term is present.

The quotes don't hurt, but they aren't the source of the problem. The missing piece is the code: part. Just Discord code:gradio works.

@JeanotZubler I use Gradio 4.16.0 with Python 3.11.7 on Windows 10. in the above link "gradio" exists in normal text form as well

@phuclv The question contains the word Gradio, but not the word Discord. The only post on StackOverflow to contain both words is the linked answer by Franck
